# Import mysql into running docker container not working

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm probably missing the obvious, but I have been scratching my head for hours now.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3' 
services:
  db:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/bitnami
      - ./backup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   networks:
     - default
  environment:
    - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MARIADB_DATABASE=mydb
```

Works just fine. Starting up is also no problem. Once it's running I do

```
docker exec -i mariadb mysql -uroot -proot mydb < backup/all.sql
```

No error, nothing, but it's not doing the import. When I take the long way:

```
docker exec -it mariadb bash
mysql -uroot -proot mydb < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/all.sql
```

it works as expected. What am I not seeing?

Comment: If you execute a line in the shell, the redirections are resolved *before* the command is executed, so this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Are you actually certain there is no import done? Because mysql might be running in batch mode if it doesn't see a tty and just not report any insertions.

Comment: yes. There is nothing in there

Answer (score 0):

I checked your similar commands, and so far I would say, it should work. Heres my working samples:

```
> echo select now() | docker exec -i mariadb mysql -uroot -proot mydb
now()
2018-04-20 21:32:38

> echo create table foo (x integer) | docker exec -i mariadb mysql -uroot -proot mydb

> echo describe foo | docker exec -i mariadb mysql -uroot -proot mydb
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
x       int(11) YES             NULL
```

So I would say your commands are correct.
Maybe the issue is in backup/all.sql ?

Comment: strange... those commands are being executed, but with no retrun, execpt for the first one which returns something very strange but definitely not a date.

echo select now() | docker exec -i mariadb mysql -uroot -proot mydb now()
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.32-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Comment: Hmm... I did not ask, what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 pro.

Comment: Do you run the shell commands with windows administrator privileges? Maybe you could try prefixing `winpty` from mingw environment.

Comment: I have win10pro ver 16299, docker Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24  (not docker toolbox, but docker on HyperV). What could be else different? I'm running docker command from cmd.exe without any additional privileges.

Comment: On cmd.exe, shouldn't backup/all.sql be backup\all.sql? Also it might be instructive to do some echo tests with `echo test | docker exec -i bash xxd` to troubleshoot. cmd.exe would also be using an 8 bit charset and \r\n line endings. If you stream an utf-8 file make sure it doesn't have a BOM at the start. I suppose docker.exe will handle the EOF translation.

Comment: It seems that cmd.exe opens its redirections in `text` mode. So the codepage that cmd.exe is running with changes everything. `chcp 65001` selects UTF-8, but I am not sure that docker.exe would support reading from the redirection in that codepage. See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html